# "Excuses to not to cook" or "excuses not to cook"?

Tags: grammar, negation, infinitives

What's the correct wording? Example sentence:

> More and more, he made excuses (to) not to cook at home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> More and more, he made excuses not to cook at home. (to do ≠ not to do) *

Or alternatively:

> More and more, he made excuses for not cooking at home.

> * Negative infinitives are normally made by putting *not* before the infinitive:
>   *Try not to be late.* (NOT USUALLY <strike>*Try to not be late.*</strike>)

*Michael Swan, Practical English Usage fourth edition, entry 89.5*

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the following two sentences to be equivalent:

> More and more, he made excuses **not to** cook at home.
>
> More and more, he made excuses **to not** cook at home.

However, this one is an error ("to" should not appear twice).

> More and more, he made excuses **to not to** cook at home.

There may be circumstances where "to not [verb]" and "not to [verb]" are different; I can't think of any off the top of my head, but I'm not thinking very hard. The main difference that I know of is that "to not [verb]" [splits the infinitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_infinitive). This is something that *some* people say we should avoid, but many others (me included) completely ignore this "rule".